# Run-Time Error 13 - Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I set up this code to identify a character in a column and split the contents of that column into as many rows as that character is present. It's been working for a while but now I'm receiving a run-time error. I tried to debug the code and it appears that the bolded line is the cause of the problem. Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this type of problem?

```
Sub splitByColB()
    Dim r As Range, i As Long, ar
    Set r = Worksheets("SheetNAme").Range("H999999").End(xlUp)
    Do While r.Row > 1
        ar = Split(r.Value, ";")
        If UBound(ar) >= 0 Then r.Value = ar(0)
        For i = UBound(ar) To 1 Step -1
            r.EntireRow.Copy         '<------------ Line causing problem
            r.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            r.Offset(1).Value = ar(i)
        Next
        Set r = r.Offset(-1)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the type mismatch but why are you offsetting up when your r range is End(xlUp)?

Comment: Won't splitting it into columns function of excel work? follow this link https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-Convert-Text-to-Columns-Wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7

Comment: The formula is meant to take data that looks like this: A | B | 1; 2; 3 and turn it into a set of three rows of A | B | 1, A | B | 2, A | B | 3 but for a set of 5 "AB" columns and 8000 total rows

Comment: Code is working for me.  It's certainly a strange line of code to give a "Type mismatch" error.  What is the value of `r.Row` when it crashes?  Is there anything strange about that row?

Comment: Why do you need this line at all? You are not using the copy anywhere.

Comment: @RADO the `insert` line will use it to create a copy by insertion.

Comment: Off-topic: [splitByColB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42425847/4926357) should be renamed `splitByColH` here. :P

Comment: difficult to assess. We can only speculate. Is your worksheet protected? do you have merged cells? any information could be useful.

Comment: Executes perfectly here. Also when r.Row is hidden, r is empty, when it's a merged cell, etc. (Excel 2016). Type mismatch is a bit strange to me, since the types are correct everywhere, it seems. Anyway I can't seem to break it.