# Split cells into multiple rows - type mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

For reference, I attempted to use the selected answer from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42425208/vba-split-cell-values-into-multiple-rows-and-keep-other-data), but I get **Runtime Error 13: Type Mismatch** error when I run the macro.

My data is setup similarly to the data in the previous question:

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD
1001    Red     Apple   A,B
1002    Blue    Pear    C
1003    Green   Plumb   D,E
```

What I need is output to look like this:

```
ColA    ColB   ColC     ColD
1001    Red    Apple    A
1001    Red    Apple    B
1002    Blue   Pear     C
1003    Green  Plumb    D
1003    Green  Plumb    E
```

I adjusted the macro to look like this (using the range as D999999, and modifying the name of my workbook):

```
Sub SplitMultipleUDC()
    Dim r As Range, i As Long, ar
    Set r = Worksheets("OUTPUT1_TEST_MACRO").Range("D999999").End(xlUp) ' The line I changed
    Do While r.Row > 1
        ar = Split(r.Value, ",")
        If UBound(ar) >= 0 Then r.Value = ar(0)
            For i = UBound(ar) To 1 Step -1
            r.EntireRow.Copy
            r.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            r.Offset(1).Value = ar(i)
        Next
        Set r = r.Offset(-1)
    Loop
End Sub
```

The error line in question points to:

```
ar = Split(r.Value, ",")
```

I can't figure out why this would be considered a data type mismatch.  I used a vlookup for the values in column D, but copy/pasted each formula result as a value.  When the macro didn't work the first time, I then converted each value to text format.  Not sure what else could be wrong.  Thanks for any help someone might be willing to offer.

Comment: What is the value of `r` when it fails?

Comment: How do I find that out?  It's my understanding that r is a variable that is set to the sheet name (OUTPUT1_TEST_MACRO) and the column where the comma separated values might exist (column D)

Comment: Here’s a guide to help you better use the VBA editor http://www.cpearson.com/excel/debuggingvba.aspx

Comment: Further to what Tim said, put a watch on `r`, and when your code breaks on error look at the `Value` property

Comment: When the code is stopped and the problem line highlighted in yellow, go the the VB editor Immediate window (Ctrl+G), type `? r.Value` and press Enter

Comment: Thanks, Tim.  
Here are the results of "? r.Value":
Error 2042

Comment: What's interesting is that if I select the entire Column D before running the macro, it does exactly what I need it to do for the last 6 lines, but then stops when it hits an #N/A value.  I'm going to try hiding them and seeing if that makes a difference

Comment: The code you show in your post works perfectly for me, given your test data. Weird.

Comment: I think it was the #N/A value.  Not every value in my vlookup was found so it resulted in an N/A.  I'm working with about 690,000 rows.  I replaced all #N/A's with blanks and it seems to be working now.  Or it may have crashed.  Can't tell.  It's running though and not erroring out so that's a good sign!

Comment: It definitely is related to the #N/A error.  The target of the `Split` function needs to be a string.  An error is not a string.  You can see this if you change that line to split the `.Text` property to force it to a string:  `ar = Split(r.Value, ",")`

Comment: Just wanted to follow-up...  The macro worked fine once I removed the N/A. 
 @TimWilliam, feel free to post the VB editor Immediate window tip as an answer and I'll select it as answer.  That was the most helpful response that allowed me to find the root issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the code is stopped and the problem line highlighted in yellow, go the the VB editor Immediate window (Ctrl+G), type

```
? r.Value
```

and press Enter.

It's possible your data contains error values which will need checking for/replacing.