# How to split a single cell with multiple softbreak delimiter into multiple rows?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have a spreadsheet where values in column F are delimited by a soft break.

[image: Currently]

I would the values in cell (F2) to be separated into multiple rows, while the values left of column F repeat themselves like in the image below.

[image: what i am trying to achieve]

I found a [post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2h5u.png) where the user is able to deliver my solution if there are only two columns.

Comment: What have you done to that code to attempt to alter for your needs?

Comment: Here is one that does the whole row: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42425208/vba-split-cell-values-into-multiple-rows-and-keep-other-data

Comment: I'm thinking this should be very doable through Power Query? Not tested.

Comment: @ScottCraner I tried this    

Lstrw = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("A2:F" & Lstrw)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code and explain where it fails.  Comments should not be used for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using Power Query in Excel. Click [ctlr] + [a] to select all and then [ctlr] + [t].

Go to the Data Ribbon and click on [From Table]
[image]

In Power Query highlight the column you are interested in delimiting. Then click [Split Column] then select [By Delimiter]

[image]

Mirror the screenshot below. Click OK and [Close & Load] on the left hand corner.

[image]

### The end result should look like this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Modified the code on this post. It generated the solution I wanted.
[VBA: Split cell values into multiple rows and keep other data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42425208/vba-split-cell-values-into-multiple-rows-and-keep-other-data)

```
Sub splitByColF()
    Dim r As Range, i As Long, ar
    Set r = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F999999").End(xlUp)
    Do While r.Row > 1
        ar = Split(r.Value, Chr(10))
        If UBound(ar) >= 0 Then r.Value = ar(0)
        For i = UBound(ar) To 1 Step -1
            r.EntireRow.Copy
            r.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            r.Offset(1).Value = ar(i)
        Next
        Set r = r.Offset(-1)
    Loop
End Sub
```